# A sports team that has a consistent record of beating another one

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests, sports

I am looking for a word or a concise expression for a sports team A that over a period of time has a consistent record of beating a rival sports team B.

It is not necessary that A are better than B. Perhaps B has more achievements, cups, championships, is higher in the league's table, has higher payed players, whatever.

But when they play against each other A wins.

In Spanish they would say that "A has B as their sons" (*los tienen de hijos*). Or that A is B's father.

I am looking for a similar expression (preferably a single word) in English.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of options:

1. [Outmatched](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outmatch) is most appropriate when:

   > Team A, over a period of time, has a consistent record of beating Team B. (paraphrased)
2. Arch-[nemesis](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nemesis). (prefix "arch-" is optional.) 
   So `A becomes B's arch-nemesis` (meaning a formidable/unbeatable foe). Side note: *rivalry* implies a sense of equality or fair chances of winning for both teams - this is not the case in your example.
3. The term "**[underdog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdog_(term))**" is used especially when a less prestigious/favourable team (Team A) is compared with a "better" or popular team (Team B). 
   `Team A is the underdog in this matchup versus Team B.` 
   When the underdog actually wins, it's called an "upset."
4. [Dark horse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_horse) is a synonym of underdog.

Please note that 2. is more poetic while 3. and 4. are common/conversational sports terms.

```
Sources: Merriam-Webster for 1 & 2
         Wikipedia for 3 & 4
```

Answer (score 1):

In the UK if team A consistently beats team B, though team B is clearly the more successful invariably finishing higher up the league table, we can say that A are their *bogey team*.

Comment: Bogey team: http://www.encyclo.co.uk/define/Bogey%20Team

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for the phrase **to have someone's number**.

> Team A has beaten team B in their last five matches. It seems that team A has team B's number.

The word **dominate** is also frequently used to similar effect when talking about sports.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the verb "to overshadow", see the first meaning [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overshadow).

Answer (score 0):

In America we say that Team A **owns** Team B.

Comment: A similar slang is `pawn`: Team A _pawned_ Team B! Or Team B got _pawned_ by Team A.

Comment: I think you mean **pwn**. A typo of *own* that gained currency via online gaming.